# java8 orElse(null.getValue()) how to handle

Tags: java, java-8

Is this possible to write in one line when `elseCondition` is null currently it's throwing `nullPointer`

here in my scenario returnValue is a String and it is null.

The conditions which i want to write is as

```java
if (returnValue != null) {
    return returnValue;
} else if (elseCondition != null) {
    return elseCondition.getValue();
} else {
    return null;
}

Optional.ofNullable(returnValue).orElse(elseCondition.getValue()) //throws nullPointer as elseCondition is null

class ElseCodnition {
    private  String value;

    getValue() {...}
}
```

Comment: What is this elseCondition?

Comment: its an object which has a String property

Comment: maybe like this `Optional.ofNullable(returnValue).orElse(Optional.ofNullable(elseCondition ).orElse(null));`

Comment: Don't use optionals, just keep this.

Comment: @HadiJ this won't work as i need to return elseCondition.getValue(); and not elseCondition

Comment: @Jigar Naik: Optional with value null inside defy the purpose of Optional. If you play with null, don't use Optional. If you play with Optional, don't return null

Comment: @JigarNaik Of course containing null is a valid use case of Optional. But I think you mean that one should avoid mixing nullable objects and optionals and I agree:

Use Optional to makle clear: every Optional might be empty, every other object will always exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elseCondition` should also be wrapped with an `Optional`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(returnValue)
        .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(elseCondition)
                        .map(ElseCodnition::getValue)
                        .orElse(null));
```

That said, I'm not sure this is a good use case of `Optional`s.

Answer (score 1):

I would have preferably used the ternary operator as:

```
return (returnValue != null) ? returnValue : 
        ((elseCondition != null) ? elseCondition.getValue() : null);
```

Molding conditional branches into chained `Optional`s doesn't sound a good for them.

Answer (score 0):

that certainly isn't a job for `Optional`, instead you can create a method which calls an object getter avoiding NPE:

```
static <T, R> R applyIfNotNull(T obj, Function<T, R> function) {
    return obj != null ? function.apply(obj) : null;
}
```

and the use case

```
return returnValue != null ? returnValue : applyIfNotNull(elseCondition, ElseCondition::getValue);
```